# How to create a session with SessionServiceProvider?

Tags: php, session, silex

I don't find my error. I can't access of the session variable.
I try this:

```
$app = new Silex\Application();
$app['debug']=true;

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SessionServiceProvider()); 


$app->get("/", function(Request $request) use($app)
{
    return  $app["session"]->get('is_admin');
});

$app->run();

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
$app->before(function (Request $request, Silex\Application $app){
    $app['session']->set('is_admin', true);
});
```

I did this to solve the problem  (thank you Stepashka):

```
$app = new Silex\Application();
$app['debug']=true;
use Silex\Provider\SessionServiceProvider;
$app->register(new SessionServiceProvider());
$app->before(function() use ($app){
    $app['session']->start();
    $app['session']->set('is_admin', "dfghjdf");
});
$app->get("/", function() use($app)
{
    return  print_r($app['session']->get('is_admin'));
});
$app->run();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thing is that your providers are not initialised before you do `$app->run()`. You should assign the value either in controller or at least after `$app->run()`.

There also is a [Middleware](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/middlewares.html) feature in Silex, so you can do your assignment like this:

```
$app->before(function (Request $request, Application $app) {
    $app['session']->set('is_admin', true);
});
```